# Who starts the OS process scheduler?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, scheduler

The scheduler manages the OS processes. But isn't the scheduler a process itself? If so, who manages it?
And i assume the scheduler needs the processor itself to run, so how does all this happen?
In my head its like the chicken and egg situation.

Comment: Can you clarify what OS you are talking about? As it is, this question is way to broad.

Comment: It's a state-machine that is entered by syscalls from running threads and by interrupts from harddware drivers.  When neither of those two things is happening, the kernel does nothing; it's just dead code and data. so it does not need to be 'scheduled'.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux scheduler is implemented in the kernel itself; it's not itself a separate process that needs to be scheduled.